# How can I get difference of two dates through MYSQL select query

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get difference of two dates (up to seconds precision) through MYSQL select query.

Can some one guide me in this regards.

Comment: Are the dates saved as Unix timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returns the difference in seconds between two dates.

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2007-01-09 10:24:46','2007-01-09 10:23:46'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF()` or `TIMEDIFF()`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html